# In Asp.Net MVC view dont render changes in model made by controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Im new to ASP.NET MVC and need some help.
When "P01" action is fired by post i receive the strongly typed model as parameter, change properties of this model instance and call "return View(model);".
In view im using "@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.p01campo01)" syntax.
Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410438/mvc3-razor-viewdata) had a similar problem and get advice to use the syntax im using.
Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642939/mvc-updatemodel-complextype) is using "<%=Html.TextBox("Person.LastName", ViewData.Model.LastName)%>" syntax.
**The problem is** when the view is rendered the textbox have the last posted value, not the value i assigned in controller.

Thanks for everyone that have tried to help me here, i put as answer the first answer that work.

There is my code:

```
*************************************************
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace MyTest.Models
{
    //-------
    public class testePg01
    {        
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "p01campo01")]
        public string p01campo01 { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "p01campo02")]
        public string p01campo02 { get; set; }

    }
    //-------
}
*************************************************

*************************************************
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyTest.Models;

namespace MyTest.Controllers
{
    public class TesteController : Controller
    {
        //-------
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]        
        public ActionResult P01()
        {
            return View();
        }
        //-------
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult P01(testePg01 model)
        {
            model.p01campo01 = model.p01campo01 + "#updatedHereButNotInView";
            model.p01campo02 = model.p01campo02 + "#updatedHereButNotInView";
            return View(model); // it dont return updated
        }
        //-------

    }
}
*************************************************

*************************************************
@model MyTest.Models.testePg01

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "P01";
}

<h2>P01</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Erro na pagina.")

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>    
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Test P01</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.p01campo01)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.p01campo01)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.p01campo01)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.p01campo02)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.p01campo02)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.p01campo02)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="P01" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
*************************************************
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it's an HttpPost HTML helpers are looking first to the POSTed data and only after that to the model.

You've to remove the property from the state:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult P01(testePg01 model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("p01campo01");
    ModelState.Remove("p01campo02");

    model.p01campo01 = model.p01campo01 + "#updatedHereButNotInView";
    model.p01campo02 = model.p01campo02 + "#updatedHereButNotInView";

    return View(model);         
}
```

Because ModelState is a dictionary you can also use `Clear()` to remove the all properties from the state:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

BTW, on MVC3 you can use `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpGet]` insted of `[Acceptverb(...)]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, your second answer works for me. I changed to [HttpPost] too. I dont understand the first answer, do you told me to remove "[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]" ? I created one action for get and another for post.

Comment: You're doing it right. One action to Post and another to Get. I was just saying that you can replace `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` by `[HttpPost]` and `[Acceptverbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]` by `[HttpGet]`. They're exactly the same think but it gets more readable that way. It's just a detail :)

Answer (score 7):

Model changes made in a post are not rendered by default. Instead it uses what was passed in the model to the controller method. To fix this, try adding:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

immediately before the RedirectToAction.

Comment: Thanks, moving ModelState.Clear(); to end now.

Answer (score 0):

this is a very ugly workaround you can try

```
 public class TesteController : Controller
    {
        //-------
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]        
        public ActionResult P01(string val1,string val2)
        {
            var model = new testePg01();
            if(!(String.IsEmptyOrNull(val1)&&String.IsEmptyOrNull(val2)))
                  { 
                       model.p01campo01  = val1;
                       model.p01campo02 = val2;

                  }
            return View(model);
        }
        //-------
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult P01(testePg01 model)
        {
            model.p01campo01 = model.p01campo01 + "#updatedHereButNotInView";
            model.p01campo02 = model.p01campo02 + "#updatedHereButNotInView";
            return RedirectToAction("P01",{val1=model.p01campo01,val2=model.p01campo02})          
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the PRG suggestion bellow. It's ugly. Instead use:

```
public ActionResult P01(TestePg01 model)
    {
        model.P01campo01 = model.P01campo01 + "#updatedHereButNotInView";
        model.P01campo02 = model.P01campo02 + "#updatedHereButNotInView";
        ModelState.Clear(); //this will re-populate the view

        return View(model);
    }
```

Use post-redirect-get pattern:

```
    public class TesteController : Controller
{
    //-------
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ViewResult P01(TestePg01 o)
    {
        return base.View(o);
    }
    //-------
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult P01Post(TestePg01 model)
    {
        model.P01campo01 = model.P01campo01 + "#updatedHereButNotInView";
        model.P01campo02 = model.P01campo02 + "#updatedHereButNotInView";
        return RedirectToAction("P01", model);
    }
    //-------
}
```

in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("P01Post", "Teste")) {//...}
```

Comment: Im new to MVC and never had listen about PRG, i found a link about it here: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201104/Blog/ASP-NET-MVC-Post-Redirect-Get-Pattern/ and here: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201007/Blog/Avoid-MVC-Anti-Patterns/

Comment: I found here: http://blog.jorritsalverda.nl/2010/03/10/maintainable-mvc-post-redirect-get-pattern/ too, PRG is necessary ?